# Download utility with dynamic bandwidth control

Tags: downloads, download-speed, bandwidth

I am looking for a CLI download tool that can **change the bandwidth limit during downloading**.

Most CLI download tools I know can set a bandwidth limit, but the limit can not be changed during downloading.

Answer (score 0):

No. The main tools for this are `wget` and `curl` and those are not interactive.

Both `wget` and `curl` do understand that you can kill and resume the download: if you want to change the speed in the middle of a download and you used the `-c` switch with the `--limit-rate=x` (for `wget`) or `--limit-rate x` (for `curl`) then you can stop `wget` or `curl` and restart it with a different speed.

There is another tool called [tc](https://www.lartc.org/manpages/tc-tbf.html) ([netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) also uses `tc`) but this will *limit the rate for the network interface of the computer*. It uses a Token Bucket Filter (TBF). 1 example ([more here](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem))

```
# tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms 10ms 25%
```

> This causes the added delay to be 100ms ± 10ms with the next random element depending 25% on the last one. This isn't true statistical correlation, but an approximation.

---

Mind that the issue of not stressing out your system can be avoided with another option `--wait=seconds`. From the [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) manual:

> Wait the specified number of seconds between the retrievals.  Use of this
> option is recommended, as it lightens the server load by making the
> requests less frequent.  Instead of in seconds, the time can be specified
> in minutes using the "m" suffix, in hours using "h" suffix, or in days
> using "d" suffix.
>
> Specifying a large value for this option is useful if the network or the
> destination host is down, so that Wget can wait long enough to reasonably
> expect the network error to be fixed before the retry.  The waiting
> interval specified by this function is influenced by "--random-wait", which
> see.

It is similar to the usage of the `Crawl-delay` directive in `robots.txt`.